# JSON array from Express route is undefined in React console

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express, routes

I am currently working on a web app to manage an external database. I am not very familiar with express or NodeJS at this point so I wanted to ask how to send a JSON object to the client sides console without getting undefined?
I have this function to connect then select the what I need and afterwards I converted my JSON object to an array of JSON objects. It displays the data fine in the console as well.

```js
async function connect() {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
  }

  info = await sequelize.query('select * from LeadsInformation', { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
  const details = JSON.stringify(info);
  console.log(details);
  detailsArray = JSON.parse(details);
  console.log(detailsArray);
}
```

Everything works fine in here, I can get the data and display it in the terminal.
This is my GET route:

```js
app.get("/list", (req, res) => {
  connect();
  res.json(detailsArray)
});
```

I have tried a couple of suggested ways based on other explanations and code snippets but none of them has worked so far so I left it like that. I thought foreaching through the data itself in the request would be a solution but it did not work. I also tried using the JSON itself and trying to display it and also tried using the body parser library. Though the library has not been updated for two years. Also I am using `axios` to fetch the data. It works fine when I try sending a simple string like "hello world" for example.

Is there anything that I'm missing or do you have any other solutions? I would also appreciate an explanation as well if possible.

Edit: It might also have to do something with how I am getting the response in the frontend. I'll look into that as well and will update this thread if I sort it out!

This is the way I get the response. I am currently trying to show in the console. I am using axios API.

```html
  Axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/list",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data.json);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have `undefined` in route because `connect` function doesn't return anything.
Also `connect` is an async function it means that it returns Promise and you have to call `.then` method or use `await` to get value from it.

Here is the code snippet with fixes that I described above.

```
async function connect() {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
  }

  info = await sequelize.query('select * from LeadsInformation', { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
  const details = JSON.stringify(info);
  detailsArray = JSON.parse(details);
  return detailsArray;
}
```

```
app.get("/list", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await connect();
  res.json(result)
});
```

*Notice that in the router handler function I also use `async` and `await` because I call `connect` which is an asynchronous function.*

Comment: Thanks! It makes more sense now. Though I was wondering is there something wrong with the way I am trying to display it in my frontend(react)? I still got undefined even after trying your snipped. After doing a test I noticed it still displays fine in the terminal but not in my frontend. My frontend is Reactjs.

Comment: You need to be sure that response from API endpoint `/list` is correct. Then you can figure out what's wrong with frontend and check clients logic. Please add code snippet from the clients app to the issue... But first let me know what is the response from endpoint `/list`.

Comment: The response from the endpoint shows undefined. It does connect since I have tested it with a basic "List page" message that was actually shown in the console so I assume it may be a problem with my client side or maybe how I sent the. I will add the snippets!

Comment: But if you meant if I got a 404 no, it actually just displays undefined, it knows I am getting a response but it is not getting received properly.

Comment: Update: I managed to fix it, there was something wrong with the way I was trying to display my response!

Answer (score 0):

The solution above did work and also another problem I had was that I wasn't getting the response correctly.
I ended up getting the response to the frontend after changing my code to the following from:

```html
console.log(res.data.json);
```

To:

```html
 console.log(res.data[1]);
```